# start JQuery UI Slider at specific value in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, leaflet, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using this [LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) library to slide through multiple layers, each of which has an associated time to the nearest half-hour, in Leaflet. I want to start the slider at the data point closest to the nearest time.

In [SliderControl.js](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/master/SliderControl.js), I replaced

```
var index_start = _options.minValue;
```

with

```
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 15) {
        minutes = "00";
    } else if (minutes < 45){
        minutes = "30";
    } else {
        minutes = "00";
        ++hour;
    }
    var time = hour + minutes;
    var times = ["000", "030", "100", "130", "200", "230", "300", "330", "400", "430", "500", "530", "600", "630", "700", "730", "800", "830", "900", "930", "1000", "1030", "1100", "1130", "1200", "1230", "1300", "1330", "1400", "1430", "1500", "1530", "1600", "1630", "1700", "1730", "1800", "1830", "1900", "1930", "2000", "2030", "2100", "2130", "2200", "2230", "2300", "2330"];
    var index_start = times.indexOf(time);
```

However, this didn't work. How can I start the slider at a specific value?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are doing it with strings instead of integers. Either way, here is one way you could do this:

**JavaScript**

```
  var now = new Date();
  var hour = now.getHours() * 100;
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var index_start = 0;
  if (minutes < 15) {
    minutes = 0;
  } else if (minutes < 45) {
    minutes = 30;
  } else {
    minutes = 100;
  }
  var t = hour + minutes;
  var times = [0, 30, 100, 130, 200, 230, 300, 330, 400, 430, 500, 530, 600, 630, 700, 730, 800, 830, 900, 930, 1000, 1030, 1100, 1130, 1200, 1230, 1300, 1330, 1400, 1430, 1500, 1530, 1600, 1630, 1700, 1730, 1800, 1830, 1900, 1930, 2000, 2030, 2100, 2130, 2200, 2230, 2300, 2330];
  index_start = times.indexOf(t);
```

Test Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qmsux550/